# E.g. Be careful on the road. There's [ many / much / a lot of ] traffic at this time of day

Tags: word-choice, modifiers

I'm teaching students quantifiers and need a bit of help with this example.

There's much traffic at this time of day. Is this incorrect? My feeling is that it's grammatically correct but yes, does feel a little strange.

I lean more towards 'There's a lot of traffic at this time...' being the correct answer but I'm unsure why it's 'more' correct than 'there's much traffic.....'

Comment: How are you defining 'correct' in this case?

Comment: Correct meaning 'my gut feeling'. My (perhaps limited) understanding is that you can use both 'much' and 'a lot of' with uncountable nouns. Is there a rule or reason that I'm missing as to why one is more natural or appropriate than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in having suspicions about *much* in *There's much traffic at this time of day*. Swan in the entry on *much* and *many* in *Practical English Usage* (page 332) says:

> In an informal style, we use *much* and *many* mostly in questions and
>   negative clauses. In most affirmative clauses they are unusual
>   (especially *much*); other words and expressions are used instead. 
>   ...
>
> In a formal style, *much* and *many* are more common in affirmative
>   clauses.

So in your case, the informal affirmative usage is *There's a lot of traffic at this time...*.

In a negative sentence or question *much* is common, but in informal contexts its alternative *a lot of* is probably equally so:

- There's not much / a lot of traffic at this time.
- Is there much / a lot of traffic at this time?

Comment: Thanks for that. Perfect.